# react js redux with materialize.ui

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

Hello I have a problem using a style in my components in materialize:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:

my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './style.css'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import  {fetchProduct} from '../../store/actions/productsFetch';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
});
class Description extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchProduct();
      }

    render() {
      const classes = useStyles();
        return (         
            <div>
  <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          alt="Contemplative Reptile"
          height="140"
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        products: state.data.filteredProducts,
        loading: state.data.loading,
        error: state.data.error
    }
  };
  const mapActionsToProps = {
    fetchProduct: fetchProduct
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(Description);
```

I would need state data from my store in parts of these components, but I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: You are using hooks inside a class component, which is not valid. See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I wonder, but I don't know how to solve this, in this component I need to work with redux changing the state getting the state

Comment: I can't find how to apply style and use redux I couldn't do it